# Can you use the free AnjLab Profiler for SQL Server Express to view the actually SQL command used to access the dababase?

Tags: sql-server

It seems the trace can only tell you something accessed the database, but not the SQL command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  It will show up in the TextData column.

As an experiment, run a trace selecting all events and all event columns.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can show the actual query fired on the database. for this you have to select appropriate events from the events list. To get the exact query select the following events :

1. SQLStmtCompleted
2. SPstmtCOmpleted
3. SQLtransaction
4. SqlfulltextQuery

Try this.